# Представление строки в бинарном виде len%8==0

Tags: python, битовые-операции, строки

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'Ввод бинарного числа'
file = (raw_input(str()))
while len(file) != 0:
    if len(file)%8!=0:
        while len(file)%8!=0:
            file = file + '0'
    file_list = list(file)
    first_8 = "".join(file_list[:8])
    print int(first_8,2),bin(int(first_8))[2:]
    file = file[8:]
```

Я получаю от пользователя на вход бинарную строку произвольной длины. Для     вывода мне необходимо, чтобы количество битов было кратно 8. Соответственно, если длина полученного сообщения уже кратна 8, то я вывожу её десятичное и бинарное представление, иначе, добавляю в конец строки нули до %8==0.

Проблема в коде : при вводе тестового значения, вывод нового бинарного представления числа не соответствует действительности (Пример : ввод - 1 вывод - 128(верно); 100110001001011010000000 (неверно, по идее : 10000000)). Как правильно отформатировать код - идей на данный момент нет.

Comment: Предположим мы считаем спички, в десятичной системе. И при этом заполняем формуляр на складе в котором под кол-во спичек в коробке отведено 4 позиции. Мы насчитали 23 спички. Пишем ... по текущей логике вашей программы мы пишем в первые 2 поля число 23 и дописываем к нему нули, что бы заполнить все позиции, получаем 2300 спичек. Вам надо накапливать данные где то отдельно, пока не наберется 8 бит. при записи, если их меньше 8 их надо дополнять нулями _слева_. спичек все таки 0023

Comment: @Mike, дополнение нулями справа вполне себе имеет право на существование, если обе стороны (инпут и конвертация) придерживаются этого правила. Дополнение нулями слева же, вообще можно не производить что используя int(value,2), что производя ручной рассчет.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем по порядку.

Входим в цикл, работающий пока длинна не нулевая

```
while len(file) != 0:
```

Далее, проверяем кратность длинны 8-ки и дополняем нулями справа. Уже заметили? При каждой итерации цикла будет производится сравнение кратности длинны, хотя работа цикла не дает шансов быть не нулевой кратности. Этот код можно вынести из цикла дабы он выполнялся лишь раз. Проверку кратности (if) также можно убрать, с ней и while справится, итого, дополнение нулями справа:

```
while len(file)%8!=0:
    file = file + '0'
```

или

```
file = file + '0' * (8 - len(file) % 8 if len(file) % 8 > 0 else 0)
```

Далее, вы отрезаете по 8-м первых символов и приобразовываете бинарное значение в десятичное. Оснановимся на выборе первых 8-ми символах.

```
file_list = list(file)
first_8 = "".join(file_list[:8])
```

Преобразовываем в лист и обратно в строку первые 8-мь значений листа. Слишком мудрено, можно же просто взять первые 8-мь символов строки

```
first_8 = file[:8]
```

Но это не понадобится, ибо с каждой итерацией цикла вы преобразовываете в десятичное значение лишь первые 8-мь бит бинарного, т.е. вы работаете со строкой не как с одним бинарным значением, а как с набором 8-ми битных бинарных значений.
Т.е. делаете совсем не то, что желаете. Для преобразования бинарного значения нужно просто его преобразовать :)

```
dec_value = int(file,2)
```

В итоге, ваш листинг сводится к

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'Ввод бинарного числа'
file = (raw_input(str()))
file = file + '0' * (8 - len(file) % 8 if len(file) % 8 > 0 else 0)
print int(file,2), file
```

Или, если хочеться поизвращаться с конвертацией, то нужно сложить произведения значений бинарной строки со степенью двойки их позиции в строке

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'Ввод бинарного числа'
file = (raw_input(str()))
file = file + '0' * (8 - len(file) % 8 if len(file) % 8 > 0 else 0)
dec_value = 0
for i, v in enumerate(file):
    dec_value += int(v) * pow(2, len(file) - i - 1)
print dec_value, file
```

Comment: Говорите дополнять справа можно ... Я беру ваш код, ввожу число "1" и получаю результат 128

Comment: @Mike, Совершенно верно, все согласно поставленной задаче. `Пример : ввод - 1 вывод - 128(верно)`. Напомню свое утверждение `дополнение нулями справа вполне себе имеет право на существование, если обе стороны придерживаются этого правила`. Вы же, вводя 1, этого правила не придерживались, подразумевая под 1 не 10000000, а что-то иное.

Comment: Хм. этого то странного условия задачи я и не заметил, мне как пользователю было бы крайне непонятно такое поведение программы. значит пример со спичками был верным, человек на складе обязан поставить ведущие нули :)

Comment: А как удобно то числа вводить ... "00000001" - 1, "000000011" - 384, "00000001 1" - abend. Ладно, это уже к постановщику задачи ...

Comment: Полностью согласен. Очень неочевидное условие без каких либо видимых причин на то. Упрощение ввода 10000000 в виде 1 очень сомнительно на фоне необходимости ввода 00000001 для единицы, которое ломает устоявшуюся логику отбрасывания ведущих нулей. Тем не менее, зача поставлена именно так, и пусть это останется на совести постановщика задачи.

Comment: @Vitalts Приведенный мною пример - лишь завершающая часть алгоритма-архиватора, которая должна выводить в файл алфавит, в котором присутствуют ASCII символы, а после стоп-символа бинарное представление закодированного текста. Проблема заключается в том, что длина двоичного кода каждого символа может отличаться , из-за чего мы не можем быть уверены в том, что длина закодированного сообщения будет кратна 8(того требует условие задачи). В качестве решения было принято писать длину бинарной строки (длина = количеству бит), а остаток заполнять "0" до кратности на 8. Код выше это должен реализовать.

Comment: @AlexSabelnikov, архиватор, который пишет двоичное представление ASCII символов забирая при этом в наихудшем варианте 8 байт на каждый символ вместо одного, или я чего-то не допонял? Ну да ладно, это уже не относится к поставленному вопросу. Пример с разъяснениями у вас есть, пользуйте :)

Comment: @Vitalts Нет, в наихудшем варианте он заберет 1 байт (8 битов на символ же).В лучшем - 1 бит (В случае введенного сообщение АББА) Я реализую алгоритм Хаффмана с выводом архивированного сообщения в файл.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать длину строки кратной 8, добавляя нули в конец строки, можно использовать [`str.ljust()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
>>> bits = input('Ввод бинарного ("01") числа: ') # Python 3
Ввод бинарного ("01") числа: 01
>>> bits.ljust((len(bits) + 7) // 8 * 8, '0')
01000000
```

Чтобы просто биты в байты преобразовать, не нужно справа добавлять нули:

```
>>> bits = input('Ввод бинарного ("01") числа: ') # Python 3
Ввод бинарного ("01") числа: 1
>>> int(bits, 2).to_bytes((len(bits) + 7) // 8, 'big') 
b'\x01'
```

Чтобы посмотреть на пример кода, который работает как на Питоне 2 так и на Питоне 3, см. [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279).

Результат (`b'\x01'`) является `bytes` объектом: неизменяемой последовательностью чисел от 0 до 255 включительно в Питоне 3. `b'\x01'` — это последовательность из одного байта (`len(b'\x01') == 1`).

Если хочется напечатать байты в десятичной и двоичной системах счисления, то можно обходить `bytes` объект напрямую (как с любой другой последовательностью в Питоне):

```
>>> for byte in b'\x01\x80': # Python 3
...     print("{0:03d} {0:08b}".format(byte))
... 
001 00000001
128 10000000
```